# Applying function with more than 1 arguments

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to apply a function to a data table which has more than 1 arguments.

Assume:

```
dt<-as.data.table(matrix(c(201,202,201,201,202,202,4,6,9,2,4,5,6,9,7,3,2,1), nrow = 6, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE))

    V1 V2 V3
1: 201  4  6
2: 202  6  9
3: 201  9  7
4: 201  2  3
5: 202  4  2
6: 202  5  1
```

I would like to apply a function with 3 arguments. For the sake of simplicity let's take a sum of them.

Obviously solution is not `dt[,sum:=V1+V2+V3]`

If I would pass 2nd and 3rd arguments in following way, it does not work.

```
dt[,sum:=lapply(V1,function(x,y,z) x+y+z,y=V2,z=V3)]
```

What is the proper way of applying a function with more than 1 arguments?

Comment: These are not same as my question is not about taking rowsums. My question was to apply function with more than one arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapply()` lets you loop over multiple vectors as arguments, using the corresponding position of the arguments with each other.

`dt[,sum:=mapply(function(x,y,z) x+y+z, V1, V2, V3)]`

```
   V1 V2 V3 sum
1: 201  4  6 211
2: 202  6  9 217
3: 201  9  7 217
4: 201  2  3 206
5: 202  4  2 208
6: 202  5  1 208
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Reduce` with `+`

```
dt[, Sum := Reduce(`+`, .SD)]
dt
#    V1 V2 V3 Sum
#1: 201  4  6 211
#2: 202  6  9 217
#3: 201  9  7 217
#4: 201  2  3 206
#5: 202  4  2 208
#6: 202  5  1 208
```

---

If there are multiple arguments, one option is `Map` with `do.call`.  Create the function of interest ('f1'), then specify the columns that will go as argument in `.SDcols`, use `do.call` with `Map` as argument, specify the function 'f1', `unlist` the output and assign (`:=`) it to 'Sum'

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z)  x + y + z    
dt[, Sum := unlist(do.call(Map, c(f=f1, unname(.SD)))), .SDcols = V1:V3]
```

Comment: This only works in the sum case, if you want to apply a function with 3 arguments instead of reducing with an associative two argument function this will not work.

Comment: @snaut It also works with `*` i.e. `dt[, Reduce(`*`, .SD)]`

Comment: Sorry `+` was too specific, `*` is an associative, two argument operation thoug.

Comment: @snaut I added another version of `mapply` for the case you mentioned